# Android UI: how to align a TextView and two radiobuttons to occupy 1/3rd parent each?

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm sure it's very simple and I'm just being stupid, but I've tried numerous variants and still can't get it working. What's worse - these 3 components are aligned exactly the way I want in the graphical editor in Eclipse, but not on the real device. I only get to align it to 50% for TextView and RadioGroup.

The XML goes like this currently (here I presumed RadioGroup is kind of LinearLayout):

```
 <RadioGroup 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/CC_Direction_caption" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_toCamera"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                    android:text="@string/CC_Backwards_Caption" />
               <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_toInfinity"
                    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                    android:text="@string/CC_Forwards_Caption" />

 </RadioGroup>
```

And the ButtonStyle is:

```
<item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">70dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
```

And all this is inside a TableRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Linear Layout with weights on your elements which will make it pretty easy to achieve what you want.

Check the docs for info on Linear Layout and weights.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Comment: Well actually it doesnt matter being in a table row you can wrap your elements in a Linear Layout and use weights to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use android:layout_centerVertical="true" in your TextView.

Below is a sample:

```
             <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="GroupBox Label"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Radio 1 Text"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Radio 2 t"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
            </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to all three elements. This specifies the relative weight every element has to the others. The higher this value is the less weight the element gets.

oh, and wrap everything in a linear layout (didn't see you didn't add a layout first).

Comment: Please see the update in the question. I've tried adding a LinearLayout into TableRow - same, no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try changing layout_width to "wrap_content" for radio buttons as well. You have already done it for the text field.